# SpringBoot : where is the login form processed?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to do an action (namely updating a field in the user table) upon successful login. Yet I can't find where the login's data get processed.

The login view part regarding this form looks like :

```
<form th:action="@{/login}"  th:object="${user}" method="post" role="login">

      <h2 class="text-center" th:text="${companyName}"></h2>

       <input type="email" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="username" th:placeholder="|Email@${clientEmailDomain}|" required class="form-control input-lg"  />

       <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Password" required="" />

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>                  

  </form>
```

The `WebSecurityConfigAdapter` includes :

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/fonts/**",
                    "/img/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/register",
                    "/resetPassword",


            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/search/" + clientOsVersion)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();

    // THIS IS ONLY DURING DEV to access to the database
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    // END OF DEV ONLY
}
```

In the login controller the following method is never called (although its counterpart "get" method is called) :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView processLoginForm(ModelAndView modelAndView,
         @Valid User user
) {

    System.err.println("Processing login data"); // This line is NEVER printed!!!

    // Here I need to update a user's attribute.

    modelAndView.addObject("clientEmailDomain",
            clientEmailDomain);

    modelAndView.addObject("companyName",
            companyName);

    return modelaAndView;
}
```

What should I do to make my `processLoginForm` method used, or where should I put my piece of code to get some job done upon successful login before reaching the `/search` route because I only want the job to be done once per session (not every time the user makes a search) ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Sounds like a job for a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler, as used with https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login

Comment: Thanks @AlexB I will have a look. So the usual form post processing would be short-circuited.